# Is there a "overscroll gesture recognizer" widget for Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there something like a `RefreshIndicator` but decoupled from its widget (essentially a "overscroll gesture recognizer").

Use case: I want to render my own progress indicators whenever the user "pulls to refresh".

(asking for someone else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html).